# TextView marquee is reset when flipping ViewFlipper

Tags: android, textview, viewflipper

My question is pretty much the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908471/android-viewflipper-resetting-my-marquee-textview)

I have a FrameLayout that contains a ViewFlipper and a TextView.

My TextView starts off by scrolling, but as soon as the ViewFlipper flips, the TextView marquee is reset.

As in the linked question, the TextView is not inside the ViewFlipper (it sits underneath it)

Any ideas?

EDIT - Some code:

View layout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".9">

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webView" />

        <VideoView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/videoView" />

    </ViewFlipper>

    <TextView
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vitae elementum ligula. In eget ligula."
        android:id="@+id/MarqueeText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip" />

</FrameLayout>
```

In my activity (oncreate):

```
marquee = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MarqueeText);
marquee.setSelected(true);
```

Thats it really. The only other thing is I have a WebInterface that flips the two child videws of the view flipper. NOTHING else is controlling the marquee text (it was added the other day with nothing but the layout and the oncreate methods.

Comment: please paste your activity code. here

Comment: AS soon as your activity changes, theContent is reset. I think you can bypass it by overriding the OnResume(), OnPause(), OnCreate() methods. Not call the setContentView

Comment: Pierre - could you elaborate a bit more on this please?